# Sinon.spy() & jest.spyOn - TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property getTableData as function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

Im trying to spy the "getTableData" method or any other class component method using jest "spyOn" or sinon "spy". All the time getting:

`Cannot spy the getTableData property because it is not a function; undefined given instead` with jest spyOn and

`TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property getTableData as function` with sinon spy.

Also the component which method Im testing is wrapped by HOC component, which is using redux connect. Then I tried to export it without HOC but test still not working with the same error

Note that `const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "getTableData");` is working fine only with component exported without HOC!

What I've already tried:

```
const spy = sinon.spy(MonthlyProjectPlan.prototype, 'getTableData');

//const spy = jest.spyOn(MonthlyProjectPlan.prototype, 'getTableData');

    const wrapper = mount(
      //<Provider store={store}>
            <MonthlyProjectPlan {...propsPanel} />
      //</Provider>
    );
```

```
export class MonthlyProjectPlan extends React.Component {
  groupBy = (list, keyGetter) => {
    //some secret magic
  };

  getTableData = () => {
    let result = [];
    if (this.props.data) {
      let groupedData = this.groupBy(this.props.data, item => item.commodity);
      // magic
    }
    return result
  };

  getTableColumns = () => {
    let tableData = this.getTableData();
    let columns = [
      {Header: 'Commodities', accessor: 'commodity', width: 300}
    ];

    if (tableData.length > 0) {
      let months = tableData[0].data.map(item => item.year_month_date);
      let monthsColumns = months.map((item, key) => {
        //magic
      });
      columns.push(...monthsColumns)
    }
    return columns
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.props.data)
      return (<LoadingBar/>);
    if (this.props.data.length < 1)
      return (<NoData/>);

    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable data={this.getTableData()}
                    className="monthly-pipeline__table"
                    columns={this.getTableColumns()}
                    defaultSorted={[{id: "commodity", desc: false}]}
                    showPageSizeOptions={false}
                    showPagination={false}
                    minRows={false}/>

        <div className="monthly-pipeline-help">
          <div className="monthly-pipeline-help__title">
            Monthly Pipeline Shortfalls Percent
          </div>

          <table className="monthly-pipeline-help__table">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style={{backgroundColor: colors.darkGreen}}>0% - 25%</td>
              <td style={{backgroundColor: colors.yellow}}>26% - 50%</td>
              <td style={{backgroundColor: colors.orange}}>51% - 75%</td>
              <td style={{backgroundColor: colors.red}}>76% - 100%</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Panel(MonthlyProjectPlan)
```

Test below is not working

```
it("should render MonthlyProjectPlan Global component correctly", () => {
    const spy = sinon.spy(MonthlyProjectPlan.prototype, 'getTableData');
    //const spy = jest.spyOn(MonthlyProjectPlan.prototype, 'getTableData');
    const wrapper = mount(
      //<Provider store={store}>
      <MonthlyProjectPlan {...propsPanel} />
      //</Provider>
    );
```

errors:

> "Cannot spy the getTableData property because it is not a function; undefined given instead" with jest spyOn

and

> "TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property getTableData as function" with sinon spy.

This is working fine, but only with component exported without HOC

```
  it("should render MonthlyProjectPlan Global component correctly", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      //<Provider store={store}>
      <MonthlyProjectPlan {...propsPanel} />
      //</Provider>
    );
    // const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "getTableData");
    // wrapper.instance().forceUpdate();
    // expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // expect(spy.mock.calls.length).toBe(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the *getTableData* method as a [class property](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). Therefore, the method is not defined in the prototype. It is, instead, a property of the instance you create.

What this is means is that the code (a simplified version of the code you provided):

```
export class MonthlyProjectPlan {
    getTableData = () => {
        let result = [];
        if (this.props.data) {
            let groupedData = this.groupBy(this.props.data, item => item.commodity);
            // magic
        }
        return result
    };

    render() {

    }
}
```

is the same as:

```
function MonthlyProjectPlan() {
    this.getTableData = function() {
        let result = [];
        if (this.props.data) {
            let groupedData = this.groupBy(this.props.data, item => item.commodity);
            // magic
        }
        return result
    };
}

MonthlyProjectPlan.prototype.render = function() {};
```

Note that the *getTableData* method is not defined in the prototype of *MonthlyProjectPlan* class, but rather a new method is created on every instance of the class you create.

Because of that, `MonthlyProjectPlan.prototype.getTableData` is undefined and you can not spy it.

Comment: can you explain this pls: 
"You are defining the getTableData method as a class property. Therefore, the method is not defined in the prototype. It is, instead, a property of the instance you create."
Why it happens and what should I do to make my test work?

Comment: I have edited my answer to further explain what I meant. Hope it helps!